# Why doesn't SQL LIKE work in Microsoft Access?

Tags: ms-access

I want to my make a search-statement and query things like this

```
select * from table where col like '%vkvk%'
```

But with trial and error I've come to the conclusion that access doesn't work with LIKE or
wildcard operators. Does anybody have some other solutions because I ain't so in to access actually, so I really don't know.

Answer (score 14):

Try:

```
select * from table where col like '*vkvk*'
```

Use an asterisk for the wildcard character.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use some SQL syntax that is like SQL Server, go to your Access OPTIONS and set it for "SQL 92" mode. So far as I know, this does two main things (there may be others):

1. allows you to use % and _ as wildcards instead of Jet SQL's * and ?.
2. allows you to use the non-crazy derived table syntax:

   ```
   SELECT MyTable.*
   FROM (SELECT * FROM SomeTable) As MyTable
   ```

...instead of the bollixed-up Jet method:

```
   SELECT MyTable.*
   FROM [SELECT * FROM SomeTable]. As MyTable
```

...which has problems with table and field names with spaces in them, since you have to use brackets inside the derived table definition, which breaks the Jet syntax entirely.

As I said, there may be other things it changes, but if you're a SQL Server programmer, you may find it easier to set SQL 92 mode on. On the other hand, most Access help uses Access/Jet/ACE conventions, so you may end up more confused by trying to use it.

EDIT:

Since originally posting this, I've discovered that there are problems with turning on SQL 92 mode in an existing Access application. The two I discovered were:

1. It changes the list of reserved words, which means that SQL that previously worked with the SQL 89 list of reserved words can break (if it uses a SQL 92 reserved word).
2. It can break multi-column combo boxes with a hidden first column (which is a very common UI object in Access applications). Specifically, it breaks the Autoexpend/autoselect behavior.

There may be other problems, but I discovered these accidentally when I turned on SQL 92 mode in a client project to test something for SO and forgot to turn it off when I distributed the next update. Fortunately, the problems were quickly detected, and it didn't take me too long to idenfity SQL 92 mode as the cause of the problems.

In short, I don't consider SQL 92 mode in Access to be of use to anybody at all. It's a feature aimed at people who won't be using Access interactively in the first place, seems to me.

Answer (score 0):

like `'%kvk%'` sometimes work sometimes don't

With Access 2010 with sql server (2008) linked tables

Use `'*kvk*'`

Answer (score 0):

I tried several "Like" syntax on one request, (I'm using VB.NET and a MS-ACCESS 2010 database), and none of them could get any other result than throwing an exception.Why? I'm not having any idea about that.

I did this workaround that could be useful on some similar cases: 
Instead of

SELECT dbFieldDisplayName FROM dbTableName WHERE dbFieldSearchName Like 'A*'

I Used:

SELECT dbFieldDisplayName FROM dbTableName WHERE dbFieldSearchName >='A' AND dbFieldSearchName <'AZZZ'

Comment: Why was my previous answer deleted? Not written in a correct English? I know I did several mistakes on it, but I'm French, would like me to answer in French, instead ? It would be great to be adivised about edit from reviews before being deleted.

Comment: Because this should be a new question, not an answer to this question. It would be better to figure out why your LIKE was not working, instead of using a (kinda) clunky workaround.

Comment: Ok, starting a new topic.