# How to stop Access from "correcting" my queries?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003

When I have subqueries in Access, it tries to 'correct' them without asking and breaks the query in the process. For example,

> Select * from TblA LEFT JOIN (Select * from [TblB] union Select * from [TblC]) as SubQry On TblA.Whatever = SubQry.Whatever

This works fine when I run it the first time.  However, after I save it and try to reopen it, Access tries to be 'helpful' and changes the parens to brackets:

> Select * from TblA LEFT JOIN [Select * from [TblB] union Select * from [TblC]]. as SubQry On TblA.Whatever = SubQry.Whatever

Of course, this throws an error.  Is there an option somewhere in the options menu I can toggle to make Access stop trying to 'help' me?

(Footnote: The actual table names are more complex than "TblB" and need to be in brackets to be recognized).

Comment: +100 if I could.  I HATE this "feature" of Access.

Comment: I, for one, can't wait to see this feature in MS Word.  Imagine writing a Word document and saving it.  Later, you re-open it and discover that Word made some 'helpful' corrections to your text without asking you and without telling you. Naturally, there is no way for the user to deactivate this feature. Now how could this possibly go wrong???

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access is re-writing - and breaking - my query!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3048189/access-is-re-writing-and-breaking-my-query)

Comment: What version? it doesn't do this to me in 2007....

Comment: If your second SQL statement is in fact what it's being corrected to, Access is, in fact, making a mistake. But I suspect you've mis-transcribed it -- the derived table should look like this: `[...]. as SubQry` -- note the trailing period after the close bracket. Your actual subquery is completely invalid, though, as it is trying to UNION a SELECT statement with a table name. You can't do that. You probably mean: `[SELECT * FROM TblB UNION SELECT * FROM TblC]. as SubQry`.

Comment: Note that you can't have any square brackets inside the subquery, but Access won't put any there unless you have unrecognized expressions (as would be the case with a defective UNION).

Comment: @RolandTumble, it's 2003.  I updated the tags accordingly.

Comment: @Fenton, thanks for pointing that out.  I updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't. Parentheses aroud your subqueries are always changed to square brackets, and you have to revert this if you want to re-save.
All you could do is save the sub query as a separate query and use that one until you application is really stable, and then integrate the sub query in the main one.

Comment: You can get around this by turning on ANSI 92 SQL Mode within Access, which allows you to use traditional round brackets, but that has effects on parts of Access that are really unacceptable (for instances, it changes the list of reserved words (which can cause working SQL to break) and prevents multi-column combo boxes from expanding with Autocomplete).